# Factoring by grouping

Tags: algebra-precalculus

so I'm trying to factor this expression..

$2m + 6 - mn - 3n$

So I turn it into this:

$2(m+3) -n(m-3)$

I notice the m + 3 and m - 3 are the difference of 2 squares I think, but I'm not sure were to proceed from hereon, or if I even did the step right.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Note that $-n(m-3)=-nm+3n$ so your second term should be $-n(m+3)=-nm-3n$. It is very easy to get signs wrong so you need to check carefully.

Answer (score 3):

There is a mistake in your process of taking out common factors

$$2m+6-mn-3n=2\underbrace{(m+3)}-n\underbrace{(m+3)}$$

Comment: That is not what I wrote?

Comment: @WD40, not sure if I understood you correctly